# Replace or regexp_replace similar words with another word in a large text

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string value in pl-sql. For example :

```
'BLABLA ((example12_ BLA** example_test() BLABLABLA()* example_12)'
```

I want to replace all similar *example* words with 'example' word. Result should be like this:

```
'BLABLA ((example BLA** example BLABLABLA()* example'
```

Only last characters after example words.

This word ((example12_ should be '((example'

Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? The wording of the title shows you know the general solution. You should be able to figure out the precise patterns you need, perhaps by reading the documentation or by Googling for help. This site has lots of examples of how to use these Oracle functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
WITH dat
     AS (SELECT 'BLABLA ((example12_ BLA** example_test() BLABLABLA()* example_12)'
                   AS str,
                'BLABLA ((example BLA** example BLABLABLA()* example' AS expected_op
         FROM   DUAL)
SELECT str,
       expected_op,
       TRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (str, 'example[^ ]*( |$)', 'example ')) AS op
FROM   dat;
```

Comment: Thanks!! 
I am searching this answer : 
REGEXP_REPLACE (str, 'example[^ ]*( |$)', 'example ')